# Fetching non-empty Smart Albums

Tags: ios, swift, photokit

Using Swift4 / ios11, I am trying to fetch a collection of non-empty smart albums from a device:

```
    let smartAlbumOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    smartAlbumOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "estimatedAssetCount > 0")
    smartAlbums = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .smartAlbum, subtype: .albumRegular, options: smartAlbumOptions)
```

This is the paradigm I've seen used in many examples, however, never with specifying .smartAlbum.  The problem is that the estimatedAssetCount > 0 predicate always returns zero results:

```
<PHFetchResult: 0x1c40fce00> count=0
```

whereas if the predicate is "estimatedAssetCount >= 0", the fetch returns all smart albums empty and otherwise.  Am I missing something is relation to smart albums?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple's docs this `estimatedAssetCount` may not be accurate, and in cases where it's not available `NSNotFound` is returned.  I suspect this is what's happening to you.  In that case, I'd suggest continuing with Apple's docs suggestion, and just fetch all smart albums, and after they're fetched filter them down based on the (now accurate) `count` property.

Comment: Indeed, I am aware that the estimatedAssetCount is inaccurate, but to always return zero seems farfetched or even worthless. NSNotFound would be evaluated as a nonzero value if that had returned.  It just seems weird that so many people have been using this technique, but it appears broken for smart albums.  Of course collections are also immutable, so I don't think a post-fetch filter would work either, but I will try it and I do thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: You're right in that NSNotFound would be evaluated as non-zero, but it would not be evaluated as > 0.  I suppose I agree that always returning zero seems strange, but maybe there is some underlying reason why smart albums would behave that way.

Comment: It would not be Apple if there was not head banging involved in the process